# how to set the default value to the drop down list in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataSet dsCurrency = new DataSet();               
dsCurrency = ParamCurrency.SelectCurrencys();
ddCurrencyField.DataSource = dsCurrency;
ddCurrencyField.DataTextField = "CurrencyName";
ddCurrencyField.DataValueField ="CurrencyCode";               
ddCurrencyField.DataBind();
```

How to select a default value to the dropdownlist control using C#?

Comment: ... _Select_ or _Set_ ?

Comment: Either insert 0th element after binding through code or add item to datasource

Comment: By drop down list you mean combo box?

Comment: Need to set a currency value as default.example i need to set United States Dollar as my default currency when page is loaded

Comment: Always use `dropDownList.SelectedValue`. `dropDownList.SelectedValue="10"` after  the`DataBind()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I assume in your datasource object (dsCurrency) is not parsing the default value for the dropdown. 
So first you will have to add the default item. After binding the datasource do the following.

```
ddCurrencyField.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select --",0));
```

With the above code you will have a default/first item selected as "--Select--". If it does not select the first item then simply set the SelectedIndex to 0.

There are 2 ways to set the default item after populating a dropdown.

1. you can use the "SelectedValue" property
2. you can use the "SelectedIndex" property

Most of the code samples are given in the previous answers. But I prefer to use the "FindByValue" method.

```
ddCurrencyField.SelectedIndex = ddCurrencyField.Items.IndexOf(ddCurrencyField.Items.FindByValue(myValue));
```

If you want to write a safe code please use the second option.

Comment: Thank You Sabo Sir . It is Working Fine because of the Safe code youhave given. Thanks a Lot sir..

Answer (score 1):

If you know the value will exist:

```
ddCurrencyField.FindItemByText("YourDefaultText").Selected = true;
```

else

```
ListItem selectedListItem = ddCurrencyField.Items.FindItemByText("YourDefaultText");

if (selectedListItem != null)
{
    selectedListItem.Selected = true;
};
```

You can also find item by value :

```
ListItem selectedListItem = ddCurrencyField.Items.FindByValue("YourDefaultValue");

    if (selectedListItem != null)
    {
        selectedListItem.Selected = true;
    };
```

Comment: You need to clear/reset the selected index before setting selected index as true.

Answer (score 0):

If this dropdown list is a combobox, use this:

```
ddCurrencyField.SelectedIndex = ddCurrencyField.Items.IndexOf("Wanted Value");
```